# Hive Databases Only List default DB

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-manager

When I try to list all hive databases through Spark (1.6)

```
scala> val tdf = sqlContext.sql("SHOW DATABASES");
tdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: string]
scala> tdf.show
+-------+
| result|
+-------+
|default|
+-------+
```

When I try to list all hive databases through hive shell

```
hive> show databases;
OK
default
Time taken: 0.621 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

While in my hive, actually I already have lot of databases. Am I miss some configuration on my Cloudera cluster? Or maybe there are some problem with my hive metastore?

Comment: How you have setup the spark .. i think you are missing coping  hive-site.xml copy at spark conf directory..

Comment: FWIW, you should look into installing Spark2

Comment: I already try to copy the file, but it return another error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use HiveContext to fetch data from the hive. set `hive.metastore.uris` by

spark code -

```
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://hostserver:9083")
val hivecontext = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
val tdf = hivecontext.sql("SHOW DATABASES");
```

spark-shell

```
spark-shell --driver-java-options "-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://hostserver:9083"
```

Comment: ya, its working after passing thrift url as argument: 
spark-shell --driver-java-options "-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://hostserver:9083"

Answer (score 0):

Since `Hive` shell also shows only `default` database, the `Hive` metastore configuration can be checked.

To start with, you can log into the database having the metastore, and run this query that should list `Hive` databases. Example query for `MySQL` database is:

```
mysql> SELECT NAME, DB_LOCATION_URI FROM hive.DBS;
```

Then, you can verify and update `hive-site.xml` as per below. The location of this file on `CDH` is generally at `/usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`, and on `HDP` is generally at `/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml`.

The documentation reference for configuration of the metastore:

a) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-RemoteMetastoreDatabase

b) (CDH) https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html (Refer to the section: *4. Configure the metastore service to communicate with the MySQL database*)

**Example configuration:**

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>
```